# How to get everything before the last occurrence of a character in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get everything before the last occurrence of a specific character from a column.

`SUBSTRING_INDEX` with negative value works well for the separation but return the part of the string I want to delete. For example, consider a column as

```
first. second. third. fourth
```

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(Col1, '.', -1)` returns `fourth`, but I want to get

```
first. second. third.
```

In fact, I want to update the same col by removing anything after the last occurrence of `.`. In other words, I want to remove `SUBSTRING_INDEX(Col1, '.', -1)` part, but I cannot simply use `REPLACE` as

```
UPDATE table1 SET Col1=REPLACE(Col1,SUBSTRING_INDEX(Col1, '.', -1),'')
```

because it may occur in other parts of the string.

Comment: What's the issue on your code? it seem like be work

Comment: @D-Shih it doesn't work if the column is `first. fourth. third. fourth`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one trick do this, making use of the `REVERSE` function:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET col =
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(col), INSTR(REVERSE(col), '.')))
```

### Demo

The idea here is to reverse the string, then use `INSTR` to find the position of the last (now first) dot.  Then, we substring from the position to the beginning, and then reverse again.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `reverse()`.  Instead:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET Col1 = LEFT(col1, LENGTH(col1) - LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Col1, '.', -1)) - 1);
```

Comment: Just curious: why wouldn't you use `reverse()`?

Comment: @ifediokonkwo … reversing the entire string is relatively expensive compared to this approach.  Also, reverse() is an extension provided by MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use `left()` and `locate()` funtion

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=53a6c111264d9225669369c1e19140dd)**

```
UPDATE table1 SET Col1= left(col1,
locate(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '.', -1),col1))
```

OUTPUT:

```
val
first. second. third.
```

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work like my `REPLACE` example. It `LOCATE()` the first `SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '.', -1)`. Thus, it doesn't work for `first. fourth. third. fourth`.